# Example of an embedding $F$ with a given property

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose $F:M\rightarrow N$ is an injective immersion between smooth manifolds. Is there an embedding $F$ such that there is a compact subspace $K$ of $N$ with $F^{-1}(K)$ is not compact?

Comment: An embedding is not the same as an injective immersion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Right. I changed the title.

Comment: So, what are your thoughts about the problem? Did you at least try to analyze the case when $M, N$ are 1-dimensional?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Actually I had no idea how to approach this problem. I wanted to start from here where $F:[0,1]\rightarrow S$ but wasn't able to get further. Should I approach this problem thinking about dimensions? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please make the text consistent. You have injective immersion and then embedding. Make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Take $M, N$ both equal to the open interval $(0, 1)$ and try to find a counter-example.